# if wireshark shows a layer 2 multicast packet on a WLAN should all connected clients receive it?

Tags: wireless-networking, android, multicast

I have an Android device connected to a WLAN via a Cisco WAP121 access point. The android device runs an app that sends out an MDNS query for services. This all works fine for a while and then I stop seeing the responses in the app.

At the point where I stop seeing the responses, a wireshark trace shows that the query is sent out and that a number of devices connected to the WLAN respond. Wireshark is running on a PC connected to the same WLAN.

The layer 2 dst shows up as ipv4mcast_fb in wireshark.

Here is a screenshot of the header of the request:

[image: multicast query header]

And here is one of the responses (several more appear in the trace as there are a number of services). This response is one from the cisco AP itself.

[image: multicast response header]

If wireshark shows a packet having a layer 2 destination as multicast does that mean that all clients connected on the same WLAN will receive that packet at their wifi interface? Or is it possible for the AP to filter out the recipients of those packets at a lower level than I am able to view?

I am trying to figure out where the fault lies. The Android app is a well established zero config tool called zeroconf browser. It is failing to find services in this setup after a time of finding them ok. Restarting the app and/or the device makes no difference. Since replacing the Cisco AP with one from a different manufacturer the problem has not been seen but I would like to find out what is unique to the Cisco case.

Comment: Can you activate "monitor mode" in your OS with Wireshark, to be able to see the actual Wi-Fi packet headers (instead of emulated Ethernet headers)? They'll tell you whether this was actually a multicast packet, or an unicast one (APs can do that conversion).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't believe I can activate monitor mode. From wireshark I have 'enable promiscuous mode' checked but I don't ever see the actual wifi packet. Is there something from the command line that might enable it? Windows 10 is my OS. I did notice that the second AP (from TP Link) does do multicast to unicast conversion for certain packets - IGMP, but not MDNS. This is the only obvious difference between the two APs that I am able to see so far. Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN#Turning_on_monitor_mode